# Crud update operation in Reactjs doesn't work

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-router, crud

I'm working on a personnal project, I wanna update some data using MVC, Reactjs and axios as frontend. can someone help me to fix this issue please. in the console there is no error it doesn't update the selected item, by the way the update op works on backend.

here is the code:

```
    constructor(props){

        super(props);
        this.updateCar = this.updateCar.bind(this);
      
        this.state = {
          car: {
            idCars: null,
            carName: "",
            carModel: "", 
            submitted: false
          }
        };
    }


  

    updateCar() {
      DataService.update(this.state.car.idCars,this.state.car)
        .then(response => {
          console.log(response.data);
          this.setState({
            idCars: response.data.idCars,
            carName: response.data.carName,
            carModel: response.data.carModel,
           
            submitted: true
          });
          this.props.history.push('/classement')  
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    }
 <button onClick={()=>this.updateCar()} className="btn btn-success" style={{marginLeft:'35%'}}>
                  Submit
                </button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is I didn't get the id of the selected car it was null so here is the answer:

```
const  updateCar = () => {
    var data = {
      id: car.idCars,
      carName: car.carName,
      carModel: car.carModel
    };

    DataService.update(this.props.match.params.id, data)
    .then(response => {
      setCar({
        idCars: response.data.idCars,
        carName: response.data.carName,
        carModel: response.data.carModel
      });
      this.props.history.push('/classement')
    })
    .catch(e => {
      console.log(e);
    });
    

}
```